# How to call elements inside user defined methods of an jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, selector

I have a jQuery Plugin which accept multiple elements and some methods to be called like:

```
(function($){

  methods = {
    init : function( options, callbacks) {
      $.fn.myPlugin.settings = $.extend({
        'userDefinedMethod': function() {}
      }, options);

      return this.each(function(){
        $.fn.myPlugin.settings.userDefinedMethod();
      }
    }
  }

  $.fn.myPlugin = function(method) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exists on jQuery.myPlugin' );
    }
  }

})(jQuery);
```

An simple example which will make you understand what I want to achieve:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myElement1, #myElement2, #myElement3').myPlugin({
    userDefinedMethod: function() {
      // I want here to use the elements in selector
      $(this).css('color', 'black');
    }
  });
});
```

I know that `$(this)` in the example above will represent the jQuery Plugin Object but I want somehow to use each element in the provided selector.

Comment: ...what is your question? The issue is not clear for me...

Comment: How to use the elements in the selector in each user defined methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myElement1, #myElement2, #myElement3').myPlugin({
        userDefinedMethod: function () {
            // I want here to use the elements in selector
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
});

(function ($) {

    methods = {
        init: function (options, callbacks) {
            //don't set the settings to shared object
            this.settings = $.extend({
                userDefinedMethod: $.noop
            }, options);

            return this.each($.proxy(function (idx, el) {
                //use Function.call() to set a custom execution context
                this.settings.userDefinedMethod.call(el);
            }, this))
        }
    }

    $.fn.myPlugin = function (method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exists on jQuery.myPlugin');
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HmXZ4/)

Answer (score 1):

In `methods.init` function `this` will be the jQuery object obtained by quering the selector. So, if you want to send `this` to `userDefinedMethod` just use `apply` or `call` when you call that function:

```
...
var methods = {
    init : function( options, callbacks) {
      $.fn.myPlugin.settings = $.extend({
        'userDefinedMethod': function() {}
      }, options);

      $.fn.myPlugin.settings.userDefinedMethod.call(this);
      // or if you want to send the arguments
      // $.fn.myPlugin.settings.userDefinedMethod.apply(this, arguments);
      return this;
    }
}
...
```

Also, don't forget that you didn't use `var` for declaring `methods`. `methods` will become a magic global variable...

I also corrected the missing `)` that was generating a syntax error.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UHTvg/2/)